# TypeError: Contract "Contract" should be marked as abstract error

Tags: solidity

GOAL: Allow anyone to send an NFT to my smart contract and create a new `Loan` struct with the received data.

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";


contract Borrow is ERC721, IERC721Receiver {
    
    mapping (uint256 => Loan) public loans;

    uint256 count;

    struct Loan {
        ERC721 nftContract;
        uint256 tokenId;
        address borrower;
        bool repayable;
    }

    
    

    function onERC721Received(
        address,
        uint256 _tokenId,
        address _borrower,
        bytes calldata
    )
        external
        virtual
        returns(bytes4)
    {
        uint256 loanId = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(address(msg.sender), _tokenId)));
        loans[loanId] = Loan({
            nftContract: ERC721(msg.sender),
            tokenId: _tokenId,
            borrower: _borrower,
            repayable: false
        });


        return 0x150b7a02;
    }
}
```

However, I keep receiving the following errors:

```
TypeError: Contract "Borrow" should be marked as abstract.
```

and

```
  | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Missing implementation: 
  --> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:44:5:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though you inherit from `ERC721` and `IERC721Receiver`, you never end up initialising nor implementing any of them in your contract.

if you remove the inheritance from the contract declaration, and you should see no errors.

`contract Borrow is ERC721, IERC721Receiver {...}`

to

`contract Borrow {...}` should do the trick

UPDATE:
Alternatively,

since you want your contract to receive NFTs(and thus be ERC721 compliant) you need to initialise the ERC721 contract you inherit.

keep your code as before `contract Borrow is ERC721, IERC721Receiver {...}` adding the constructor to initialise it like:

```
contract Borrow is ERC721, IERC721Receiver { 

constructor() public ERC721("MyNFT", "MFT") {}
//...(the rest of your contract)
}
```

Comment: When I do this, the error goes away. However, when I try to send an ERC721 token to it, I get the following error: Reason provided by the contract: "ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer".

Comment: updated answer based on your last 2 comments